# Fully opening a file in c language

Tags: c, file

is there a way in c language to open a file, not the

```
FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode);
```

but like when you double click a file and it opens on full window.

Comment: Try C# or a very high level programming language.

Comment: That `fopen` call (or something like it) is executed by the code that creates the window and loads your file into it.

Comment: @JohnBode And a dozen of abstraction layers on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is outside the scope of standard C. If you are writing a windows program, perhaps the `ShellExecute(...)` function can help you.

Comment: You did understand what the **opens on full window** means?

Comment: Eh, no, not really. I tried to interpret the question as best I could. Please enlighten me. Or, write your own answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

The word "open" is an overloaded term.  :)

When you double-click a file, the operating system lauches a program that is associated with the file type.

The simplest way to open a file in c the way the operating system does when you double-click it is probably to execute the associated program under your program's control using the sytem command.

Below is a simple program that opens "hello.txt" with "notepad.exe", assuming notepad.exe is in the path.

On Windows, I compiled it at the command line using cl.exe, which was included with Visual Studio.  On Linux, the system command is provided by unistd.h instead of process.h, and of course some other editor would probably be used.

```
#include <process.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    if (system("notepad.exe hello.txt") == -1) {
        perror("command failed");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```